# Error in BabelNet 2.5 configuration

Tags: java, configuration, slf4j

indeed I'm trying to use babelNet api 2.5 in a java class but I get this error and I don't know the cause.

```
 SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/khalifa/Downloads/apache-jena-2.12.1/apache-jena-2.12.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Bureau%20080614/bureau31122014/BabelNet/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
[ INFO  ] BabelNetConfiguration - Loading babelnet.properties FROM C:\Users\khalifa\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test2\config\babelnet.properties
[ INFO  ] BabelNet - BabelNet API v2.5 written by Roberto Navigli, Simone Ponzetto and Daniele Vannella, with additional contributions by Francesco Cecconi
[ INFO  ] BabelNet - ---------------
[ INFO  ] BabelNet - Opening dict index: D:/Bureau 080614/bureau31122014/BabelNet/dict
[ INFO  ] BabelNet - Opening gloss index: D:/Bureau 080614/bureau31122014/BabelNet/gloss
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not init BabelNet: read past EOF
    at it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelNet.getInstance(BabelNet.java:217)
[ INFO  ] BabelNet - Opening lexicon index: D:/Bureau 080614/bureau31122014/BabelNet/dict
    at Dijkestra.ContextDefinition.getDefinition(ContextDefinition.java:111)
    at Dijkestra.ContextDefinition.main(ContextDefinition.java:145)
```

the code when I used BabelNet  is here:

```
import it.uniroma1.lcl.babelnet.BabelNet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
public class ContextDefinition {
   public static void getDefinition(String v){

        try{
     BabelNet bn    = BabelNet.getInstance();
        }catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        getDefinition("bbank");
    }
}
```

I will be grateful if anyone help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the cause of the error that the folder which contains Babelnet it contains external not used folders that is  **BabelNet Precompiled Index, Core, v2.5, CC_BY_NC_SA_30 licence**. It is enough to download **BabelNet Precompiled Index Bundle, v2.5** and **BabelNet Java API, v2.5** . Removing this folders has resolved my problem. I give this solution that may help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a warning from logging. Check your classpath, you will find multiple instances of the jars listed here:

http://slf4j.org/faq.html#where_is_binding

You only need one of those in your classpath, depending on which logging library you want to use for actual logging.